# Week for a year in a bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to calculate the number of weeks in a year in a bash script. The week starts on Sunday. For the calendar year 2019 53 calendar weeks should be calculated accordingly.

The calendar week 1 starts on Sunday, 12/30/2018.

The calendar week 53 begins on Sunday 12/29/2019.

The shell script gives as result 52. `%U week number of year, with Sunday as first day of week (00..53)`

```
#!/bin/bash

week=$(date --date='2019-12-31' +%U)
echo $week
```

Comment: A year contains 52 weeks + 1 (or 2) days. Do you want to count the number of Sundays in the given year?

Comment: Tangentially, that's a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: The result for `2019-01-01` is week 0 so apparently this is zero-based, in some sense.

Comment: Is it possible to send me an idea or some lines of code?

Comment: The `man` page you quote says it clear: `(00..53)`. Weeks are zero-based. As for the `53` case, there are (indeed) years that overlap 54 weeks, such as 2006, 2012, 2017, 2023, 2028, … So you just need to add 1! (Side note: A week starts on Monday in most of the world, i.e. `%W` instead of `%U`, but that’s unrelated.) Some code: `last_week_of_year() { echo $((1 + "10#$(printf '%(%U)T' "$(date '+%s' --date="${1}-12-31T12:00:00")")")); }` It takes a December 31 noon, take its epoch, formats the epoch as the number of a Sunday-starting week, then adds 1. Example: `last_week_of_year 2019`.

Comment: @anishsane A year may _overlap_ across more weeks than it _contains_. See my comment above. E.g. years 2006, 2012, 2017, 2023, 2028 (with `%U`) or 2007, 2012, 2018, 2024, 2029 (with `%W`) overlap with 54 weeks, depending on the definition of _week_. This **differs from the ISO week numbering `%V`**, which **never** reaches 54 and rarely reaches 53 (in 2004, 2009, 2015, 2020, 2026, for example). Then it depends on what one really considers the _nubmer of weeks in a year_; it is 53 at most by the ISO week numbering, but it can be 54 when counting _all_ weeks a year really overlaps with.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek : FYI : 2023 also generates answer of `54`, whereas 2022, 2024 return `53`. Nice helper function! Cheers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the output you expect for each of the years from 2010 through 2020 as that would clarify your requirements a lot.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "number of weeks in a year"?

Is it the number of weeks that consist *entirely* of dates in that year? (51-52)

Is it the number of weeks where more than half of their days are in the year (52-53, ISO definition if weeks start on Monday)?

Is it the number of weeks that contain *any* dates in that year? (53-54)

You'll get three different answers depending on what you pick.  There are different "week numbers" that go with those options, but even within each option you have to pick whether weeks start on Sunday or Monday, and whether the first week is week 0 or 1.

Note that if you're counting up weeks across years, only the middle option will get you the right answer; the first will undercount by skipping weeks that overlap two years, while the third will overcount by including such weeks twice.

It sounds like you want the third option (number of weeks with *any* days in the given year), where weeks start on Sunday. That's almost `date +%U`, except that days in January before its first Sunday are considered part of week 0 rather than week 1, so the total count of weeks is almost always one more than the week number of December 31st. Since it's not *quite* always (there's no extra week when the year starts on Sunday), you can easily check to make sure that the addition is necessary:

```
countWeeks() {
    local year=$1

    local lastweek=$(date +%U -d "$year-12-31")
    local firstweek=$(date +%U -d "$year-01-01")
    # Note: the above is for GNU date(1); for BSD/macOS:
    # local lastweek=$(date -j +%U "12311200$year")
    # local firstweek=$(date -j +%U "01011200$year")
   
    if (( firstweek == 0 )); then
       (( lastweek += 1 ))
    fi
    printf '%d\n' "$lastweek"    
}
```

Which gets the desired result:

```
$ y=2019
$ printf '%d has %d weeks\n' "$y" "$(countWeeks "$y")"
2019 has 53 weeks
```

I don't know how useful that is; within a given century¹, 27 out of every 28 years will have 53 weeks by this reckoning. The remainder – leap years starting on Saturday such as 2000 and 2028 – will have 54.

¹ The centennial leap year rule bumps the figure from 27/28 to 387/400 overall.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you want, using GNU date:

```
y=2017; date -d "$y-12-31 -$(date -d "$y-12-31" +'%w') day" '+%U'
```

That figures out the weekday number (from Sun=0) of the last day of the year using `date -d "$y-12-31" +'%w'`, then subtracting that number of days from the last date of the year which backs the date we're printing `%U` for up to the first Sunday before that if it's not already a Sunday, i.e. it'll print the week number of the last Sunday of the year.

Here's a test:

```
$ for (( y=2010; y<=2020; y++ )) do
    date -d "$y-12-31 -$(date -d "$y-12-31" +'%w') day" '+%U %F %A'
done
52 2010-12-26 Sunday
52 2011-12-25 Sunday
53 2012-12-30 Sunday
52 2013-12-29 Sunday
52 2014-12-28 Sunday
52 2015-12-27 Sunday
52 2016-12-25 Sunday
53 2017-12-31 Sunday
52 2018-12-30 Sunday
52 2019-12-29 Sunday
52 2020-12-27 Sunday
```

If that doesn't do what you want then please edit your question to tell us one or two years where it fails and why that's the wrong approach.